# Named Parameter Jdbc Template Bean not instantiating

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

I am trying to @Autowire the NamedParameterJdbcTemplate dependency into my Dao, but I am getting printing null to the console when I try and 'syso' the object.

Here is my dao:

```
package com.atmWebApp.daos;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.MapSqlParameterSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import sun.jdbc.odbc.ee.DataSource;

import com.atmWebApp.entities.Account;

@Component
public class AccountDao {

    @Autowired
    NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate;

    public Account getAccountByAccountIdAndPin(String accountId, String pin){
        System.out.println(namedParameterJdbcTemplate);
.....
```

Here is my app-servlet:

```
<bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/********" />
        <property name="username" value="postgres" />
        <property name="password" value="*******" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="namedParameterJdbcTemplate"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
```

What is the issue I am having?

Comment: Where and how are you using `AccountDao`?

Comment: how are you getting the instance of AccountDao ?

Comment: AccountDao is my class in which I interface with the database. I instantiate it in my AccountService class, which is an middleman from my controller to my dao.

Comment: when you say instantiate, it is autowired inside account service or you doing new AccountDao ?

Comment: I am using AccountDao accountDao = new AccountDao();